# W3 Jmail not working (ActiveX component can't create object)

Tags: asp-classic, activexobject, jmail

I am moving the website by setting up a new server and an error is occurring where I try to pull up Jmail and unable to launch the website at the moment.
For your information, I installed Jmail 32 bit version.
Please tell us how to solve the problem.

**Development environment**
Microsoft Windows Server 2016
IIS 10
Classic ASP

**Error Message**
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01ad'
ActiveX component can't create object
/email.asp, line 34

**Line 34 is below.**
set jmail = Server.CreateOBject( "JMail.Message" )

Comment: Did you restart IIS after installing the component? Also, select your Application Pool > Advanced Settings, and make sure "Enable 32-Bit Applications" is set to True.

Comment: I did what you said.
But still, the error doesn't go away.
Thank you, Adam.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the jmail.dll has been registered correctly

c:\windows\system32\regsvr32 c:\windows\system32\jmail.dll

Check paths for location in your environment.